# Configure jetty request logs

Tags: jetty

I am using solr-7.2.1 version and it has embedded jetty server, verison-9.
    I have tried to enable requestlog module to configure request logs but did not work.
    I have installed http,https modules. Failed to install the remaining modules like webapp,deploy,requestlog.

```
Could someone suggest a fix?

Output of these modules:
Steps:
-bash-4.1$ sudo java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=http
INFO: http            initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: Base directory was modified

-bash-4.1$ sudo java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=https
INFO: https           initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: Base directory was modified

-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$ sudo java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=webapp
org.eclipse.jetty.start.graph.GraphException: Missing referenced dependency: webapp
  at org.eclipse.jetty.start.graph.Graph.selectNodes(Graph.java:470)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.start.BaseBuilder.build(BaseBuilder.java:152)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:407)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
 Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
   java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$ sudo java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=deploy
 org.eclipse.jetty.start.graph.GraphException: Missing referenced dependency: deploy
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.graph.Graph.selectNodes(Graph.java:470)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.BaseBuilder.build(BaseBuilder.java:152)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:407)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
   java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$ sudo java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=requestlog
org.eclipse.jetty.start.graph.GraphException: Missing referenced dependency: requestlog
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.graph.Graph.selectNodes(Graph.java:470)   
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.BaseBuilder.build(BaseBuilder.java:152)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:407)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
   java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$
```